# Having trouble in specifying datetime datatype with doctrine annotation

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, annotations, doctrine

I have Doctrine 2.7 installed with composer. I am using annotations in my entity this way:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTimeImmutable
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz_immutable", nullable=true)
 */
private $createTime;
```

But when I run

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

It outputs

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE createTime createTime INT DEFAULT NULL;
```

This is not what I expected. I expected that the MySQL datatype will be DATETIME or TIMESTAMP not INT.

Please I need help on what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional google searching I found that it was because of the cached metadata

It worked fine after running this

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
```